# Integer.parseInt() Error

Tags: java, parseint

i'm getting an errors while trying to use `Integer.parseInt()`. They are, no suitable method found for parseInt(int) and method Integer.pasreInt(String) in not applicable.

```
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

class bday1
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int day;
    int month=0;
    int year;
    int whatDay;
    int howManyDays=0;
    int leapYear;
    final int JANYEAR = 1901;
    int[] dayMonth = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    boolean numberEntered=true;
    String strMonth;
    String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    System.out.print("What is your birthdate? "); 
    sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[-/.\\s]")); 
    day = sc.nextInt();
    strMonth = sc.next();
    year = sc.nextInt();

    if((strMonth.charAt(0) >='0') && (strMonth.charAt(0) <='9'))
    {
        numberEntered=true;
        System.out.println ("number entered");
    }

    if(numberEntered)
    {
        strMonth=Integer.parseInt(month);
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println ("string entered");
    }
```

Thats my snippet of code i believe i having trouble with. Any help would be great.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between parameters and return values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you post a question regarding an error, you need to supply the error you're getting and when it occurs. (In this case, I suspect you get the error when you try to compile this code.) It also helps to try to remove as much of your code that doesn't cause the error as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since month is initialized to zero and isn't changed afterwards, setting `strMonth` to `month` would only succeed in setting it to 0. By the looks of your code, it appears that you are trying to set the value of `month` to `strMonth`. To do this, replace:

```
strMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
```

With the following:

```
month = Integer.parseInt(strMonth);
```

Comment: That stops the errors, but it returns a value of 0 regardless of what a put in. Any ideas?

Comment: Taking another look over your code, I noticed that you are probably trying to set `month` to `strMonth`, as `month` would otherwise be stuck as 0. I've edited my answer appropriately. @EthanEdwards

Comment: Compiles fine, but if the user inputs for example: 15/july/1993 it returns a numberformatexception

Comment: ah fixed it, as booleans are always set to true, it was entering the if statement where it was parsing the int. which was returning errors. i made an else statement where `numberEntered=false;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the String value into the int dataType. so only it wont allow you.

```
strMonth= Integer.parseInt(month); // variable month and strMonth is int dataType
```

And then the `Integer.parseInt()` will return the String value. Change the type to String or convert the String to int

try

```
strMonth = String.valueOf(month);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code you are use parseInt which expects a String.  The month that you are using is already an int.

What you are trying to do is convert an int to a String.
Normal ways would be `Integer.toString(i)` or `String.valueOf(i)`.